# What does the phrase " no more than the next person" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

https://www.lingq.com/lesson/lesson-16-obsessive-compulsive-disorder-431409/

LISA:
I used to work as a teacher. I never thought of myself as a worrier, at least **no more than the next person**.

What does the phrase " no more than the next person" mean? I guess it means "no more than anybody else" but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next person refers to a random person, which means Lisa does not worry more than what is considered average for a person.